# Angular Queuing the requests at one place and subscribe them after the request in progress are Completed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Behaviour to achieve: Send N number of requests at at time and once the N number is exceeded request should be queued and only to be sent to server when in progress requests are completed. In this case N can be 4 or 5.

Why to do this?
I want this behaviour because i have ping request which checks user login whihc is getting blocked in queue because of other requests and user gets logout.

How we can achieve this in angular as we have different requests calling different methods from different component.
Can this be solved by interceptor?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make queuing in Service and not in inteceptor as interceptor not meant for queue its meant to add some things to reuest like header(for stop repeatation) before sending to server.